# Resizing with Viewbox, Canvas and Drag-Drop items

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-controls, viewbox

I want my application to have a `Canvas` overlaying a background `Image`. The `Canvas` will contain objects (`TextBlocks`, etc.) that can be repositioned (setting `Top`, `Left`) via drag-drop.

The application will need to have some sizing options: `None`, `Fill`, `Uniform`. Or users can set specific dimensions.

When these sizing options are tweaked, the `Canvas`, `Image`, and all of the child objects will need to all be re-sized so that everything "scales" correctly. In other words, in addition to the background `Image` scaling, the drag-drop items need to be repositioned correctly.

I started out by using a Viewbox as the "container" control, and everything seems to "scale" just fine setting the Stretch property to None, Fill, Uniform options.

```
<Viewbox x:Name="Viewbox">
   <Grid>
      <Image x:Name="Image" Stretch="Fill" Source="Background.bmp" />
      <Canvas x:Name="Canvas" Background="Transparent">
         <TextBlock Text="Test1" Background="Gray" Canvas.Top="170" Canvas.Left="50" />
         <TextBlock Text="Test2" Background="Gray" Canvas.Top="225" Canvas.Left="80" />
         <TextBlock Text="Test3" Background="Gray" Canvas.Top="170" Canvas.Left="150" />
      </Canvas>
   </Grid>
</Viewbox>

private void StretchModeComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   this.Viewbox.Stretch = (Stretch)this.StretchModeComboBox.SelectedValue;
}
```

To achieve the specific dimension sizing, I naively changed the dimensions on the Canvas, Image, and Viewbox. The problem here is that the drag-drop objects are not repositioned correctly. They remain at their original Top, Left settings which is not correct.

```
private void ResizeButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   this.Viewbox.Stretch = Stretch.None;

   this.Viewbox.Height = this.Canvas.Height = this.Image.Height = Convert.ToDouble(this.HeightTextBox.Text);
   this.Viewbox.Width = this.Canvas.Width = this.Image.Width = Convert.ToDouble(this.WidthTextBox.Text);
}
```

To achieve the specific dimension functionality, I think I need to simulate a height/width change using a ScaleTransform? Does this sounds like the right way to go? That way everything scales when the user puts in specific dimensions.

How does one translate specific dimensions (height/width) into parameters to pass to a scale transform?

Here is the application with the default sizing options (notice the TextBlocks with the gray background - Test1, Test2, Test3)

[image]

Here is the application with the Fill option set (again notice that the TextBlocks remain).

[image]

Finally, here is the application with specific dimensions set (1000 x 1000) (notice that the TextBlocks remain at their original Top and Left settings). This is not what I want to happen. I want them to be repositioned relative to their origin.

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you get vs what you expect?

Comment: Updated to include screenshots.